# Using lines in perpendicular form to find distance from origin

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: question]

I'm having trouble with part b and c (although I think I'll be fine with part c if I understand part b). I think I need to find the coordinate of the 90 angle of the little triangle but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Look at the small triangle with one side on the $x-$axis. The angle the perpendicular dropped from $O$ to the line $\ell$ makes with $x-$axis is $\theta$. Let $d$ be the distance of the line from $O$. Then  $$\cos \theta=\frac{d}{c/a}.$$ Now solve for $d$.

Comment: How do you know it is theta? Similar triangles or is it just a random unknown

Comment: $\theta$ is already given in the figure you provided. It is the angle that $\ell$ makes with the $y-$axis. Now use basic geometry to claim that $\theta$ is also the angle I referred to in my comment.

Comment: I see. Thank you, it worked quickly